# Why is training so slow on my neural network?

Tags: python, performance, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have two feed forward neural networks (built with keras in python) performing a similar task, yet the training time is completely different, I can't figure out the cause of this.

I have a neural network taking inputs and outputs of shape:
input shape: (100000, 21) output shape: (100000, 9),
the first axis being the number of training samples, and the second the number of nodes in the input and output layer respectively.
Then I have another neural network taking a subset of the above inputs and yielding a subset of the above outputs as such:
input shape: (100000, 13) output shape: (100000, 1)
Other than this difference, the settings are exactly the same. Yet the first network is significantly faster to train, what could be causing this?

These settings are:
a regression problem with 5 hidden layers of 128 nodes with relu activation functions, adam optimizer, linear activation for the output layer. I suppose the number of epochs is also different, but that shouldn't make a difference for the training time per epoch as far as I'm concerned. Batch size is 64, glorot-normal initialization.

Here is some of the training output that keras provides of each network respectively, note that the network with less input and output nodes is significantly slower:

```
input shape: (100000, 21) output shape: (100000, 9),
Train on 90000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/500
90000/90000 [==============================] - 3s 31us/step - loss: 0.3145 - val_loss: 0.1749
Epoch 2/500
90000/90000 [==============================] - 2s 23us/step - loss: 0.1426 - val_loss: 0.1298
Epoch 3/500
90000/90000 [==============================] - 2s 23us/step - loss: 0.1161 - val_loss: 0.0999
Epoch 4/500
90000/90000 [==============================] - 2s
```

```
input shape: (100000, 13) output shape: (100000, 1)
Train on 90000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/100
90000/90000 [==============================] - 36s 398us/step - loss: 0.0922 - val_loss: 0.0525
Epoch 2/100
44608/90000 [=============>................] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.0503
```

The training time per epoch does not decrease beyond 24 seconds in the second case, although I expected it to be faster given any form of stochastic gradient descent requires fewer gradient calculations given less input.

Here is the code for the first neural network:

```
# initiate:
model = Sequential()

# add hidden layers
model.add(Dense(nodes, input_dim = n, activation='relu', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal'))
for i in range(layers):
    model.add(Dense(nodes, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal'))

# add output
model.add(Dense(out, activation = 'linear', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal')) 

# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# fit the keras model on the dataset
print('input shape:',np.shape(X_norm), 'output shape:', np.shape(L_norm))
history = model.fit(X_norm, L_norm, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split = (1/10) 
                   , callbacks = [earlystop])
```

The second network is exactly the same, apart from the number of input in model.fit:

```
# fit the keras model on the dataset
    history = model.fit(inputdt, outputdt, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split = (1/10) 
                       , verbose = 1, callbacks = [earlystop])
```

where inputdt and outputdt are slices of X_norm and L_norm respectively.

Comment: please post some code with which it would be possible to help you

Comment: I added the lines building the networks, hope this helps

Comment: is `layers` the same in both? How is it defined? what happens if you do not use `verbose=1` in your second call?

Comment: layers = 4 in both cases, I just tried and changing verbose does not make a difference unfortunately